# Does paypal vault has GUI?

Tags: paypal

I have integrated Paypal Vault (PHP REST SDK). But i could't found the link to see the list of saved cards and users.

Is it possible to the list of saved records in Paypal? If yes where can I see those?

I followed this [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#store-a-credit-card)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no GUI for vault stored cards.
You will need to store the vault ID on your end and reference this in call made.